Adding Multiple Titles with Gilded Effects
In Giving a Title a Gilded Effect, I asked how to give a "gilded effect" to the lettering in the title; to which, hpekristiansen gave a very nice answer in which both the title and ornaments are gilded---that is, display a metallic effect:
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.7in, vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament, tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gold}{RGB}{215,190,105}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{1,50,32}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myborder, color=transparent!0, inner sep=0.6cm]
\node[below right] at (current page text area.north west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm]{63}};
\node[below left ] at (current page text area.north east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=v]{63}};
\node[above right] at (current page text area.south west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=h]{63}};
\node[above left ] at (current page text area.south east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=c]{63}};
\node[below] at (current page text area.north) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm, symmetry=h]{71}};
\node[above] at (current page text area.south) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm]{71}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=mytext, color=transparent!0]
\node (n) at (current page text area) {\swabfamily{\scalebox{6}{Gilded}}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\fill[darkgreen] (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
\fill[path fading=myborder, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={xshift=1pt, yshift=-1pt}] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\fill[path fading=myborder, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\fill[path fading=mytext  , fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={yshift=-1.35pt}]  (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
\fill[path fading=mytext  , fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

with output:

A while later, I encountered difficulty in adding "gilded" titles to the overall frame; and hence, posted the question Positioning Multiple Fading Titles with Tikzpagenodes to which @cfr responded with a rewriting of the above code to facilitate the adding of multiple gilded titles:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,paperwidth=4.375in,paperheight=7.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gold}{RGB}{215,190,105}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{1,50,32}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myborder, color=transparent!0, inner sep=0.4cm]
  \node[below right] at (current page text area.north west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm]{63}};
  \node[below left ] at (current page text area.north east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=v]{63}};
  \node[above right] at (current page text area.south west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=h]{63}};
  \node[above left ] at (current page text area.south east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=c]{63}};
  \node[below] at (current page text area.north) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm, symmetry=h]{71}};
  \node[above] at (current page text area.south) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm]{71}};
  \node [anchor=south] (n) at ([yshift=5pt]current page text area) {\swabfamily{\Huge\scalebox{2}{Gilded}}};
  \node [anchor=north]  at ([yshift=-5pt]current page text area) {\large\scalebox{2}{\swabfamily{More Gilded}}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \fill[darkgreen] (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
    \fill[path fading=myborder, fit fading=false, fading 
    transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

with output

I have now noticed that the gilded effect of the ornaments appears to be gone; as well as, the gilded effect of the title given in the @hpekristiansen answer is somewhat diminished.
QUESTION: How may the hpekristiansen code be modified to allow the inclusion of multiple gilded titles while faithfully maintaining the quality of the gilded finished in both the titles, as well as in the ornaments?
Thank you.

It's not actually gone. It is just diminished because I only applied the shading once. (At least, I think that's why.)

@cfr: It is not about the number of times the shading is applied, but to what area. A ball shading applied to the whole page will be a somewhat uniform color in the small central area containing the nodes. In the below solution, I reapply the shading, but just for the area with the nodes.

@hpekristiansen Yes, I wasn't very precise. I should have said I only applied it once and in one place. You multiply the lightening effect by applying it multiple times (to smaller areas). I guess I was taking that for granted since otherwise you'd end up only highlighting one place. I think ideally, you'd use a custom shading here, but TeX isn't really made for this so I doubt it would be worth it ;).

\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,paperwidth=4.375in,paperheight=7.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gold}{RGB}{215,190,105}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{1,50,32}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=mypage, color=transparent!0, inner sep=0.4cm]
\node[below right] at (current page text area.north west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm]{63}};
\node[below left ] at (current page text area.north east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=v]{63}};
\node[above right] at (current page text area.south west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=h]{63}};
\node[above left ] at (current page text area.south east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=c]{63}};
\node[below] at (current page text area.north) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm, symmetry=h]{71}};
\node[above] at (current page text area.south) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm]{71}};
\node [anchor=south] (n1) at ([yshift=5pt]current page text area) {\swabfamily{\Huge\scalebox{2}{Gilded}}};
\node [anchor=north] (n2) at ([yshift=-5pt]current page text area) {\large\scalebox{2}{\swabfamily{More Gilded}}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\fill[darkgreen] (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
%add ball shading for each area
\shade[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\shade[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (n1.south west) rectangle (n1.north east);
\shade[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (n2.south west) rectangle (n2.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Edit: Now also with a shadow as in the original:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,paperwidth=4.375in,paperheight=7.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gold}{RGB}{215,190,105}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{1,50,32}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=mypage, color=transparent!0, inner sep=0.4cm]
\node[below right] at (current page text area.north west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm]{63}};
\node[below left ] at (current page text area.north east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=v]{63}};
\node[above right] at (current page text area.south west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=h]{63}};
\node[above left ] at (current page text area.south east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=c]{63}};
\node[below] at (current page text area.north) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm, symmetry=h]{71}};
\node[above] at (current page text area.south) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm]{71}};
\node [anchor=south] (n1) at ([yshift=5pt]current page text area) {\swabfamily{\Huge\scalebox{2}{Gilded}}};
\node [anchor=north] (n2) at ([yshift=-5pt]current page text area) {\large\scalebox{2}{\swabfamily{More Gilded}}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\fill[darkgreen] (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
%shadows
\fill[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={xshift=1pt, yshift=-1pt}, even odd rule] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east) (n1.south west) rectangle (n1.north east) (n2.south west) rectangle (n2.north east) ;
\fill[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={yshift=-1.35pt}]  (n1.south west) rectangle (n1.north east);
\fill[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={yshift=-1.35pt}]  (n2.south west) rectangle (n2.north east);
%add ball shading for each area
\shade[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\shade[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (n1.south west) rectangle (n1.north east);
\shade[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (n2.south west) rectangle (n2.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Many thanks for this answer; however, it seems to me that the gilded finish (especially in the ornaments) in your original code is much sharper and more "metallic". Do you know why this appears to be so?

I went for a bit of a detour, before I finally now understand that you probably meant the black shadow effect on everything. -see edit.

Many thanks once again, for a fine answer.
